# How can I change my Khajiit character into a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Okay, my character on Skyrim is a Khajiit and IM not very far in the game....but i would like to know where i have to go in order to become a werewolf?

Answer (score 6):

Your character's race doesn't matter. You will become a werewolf by following the Companions quest line. You can join the Companions by visiting Jorrvaskr in Whiterun, close to the jarl's keep.